# A Word to describe the action of removing double-strapped backpack from your back?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that can explain this action in a word rather than writing a lengthy sentence. Any guidance or corrections are appreciated.

Comment: He *took off* his backpack. He *threw off* his backpack. He *shrugged off* his backpack. He *debackpacked*. (That last one uses a made-up word.)

Comment: @IanMacDonald - *He reduced himself to an unbackpacked state* or he was now *disembackpacked*

Comment: He defenestrated the backpack.  (Only applicable if he's near a window.)

Comment: If this was a heavy backpack it's worthy of a "heavy" sentence.  Having hauled a few backpacks in my time I know that removing a heavy one is often awkward but the sensation after setting it down (and maybe sitting down yourself) is near euphoric.  If this is a story the backpack is one of the characters.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the context of course, but maybe sloughed?

> "To get rid of (something undesirable or no longer required)."

She sloughed off her backpack and sat down.

Answer (score -1):

Trundle

> "to cause a heavy, awkward, object to roll along"
>
> Her heavy backpack trundled off.